# Why this query is not working

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL so I don't understand why this this query is not working. Thank you in advance

```
CREATE VIEW temp AS
SELECT return_date_time, renting_date_time
FROM renting;

CREATE TRIGGER charge_calc AFTER UPDATE ON renting.return_date_time
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE renting
    SET new.charge =(select m.charge_per_day 
             from movies m,renting as r 
             where (m.id=r.id_movie))*datediff(temp.return_date_time,temp.renting_date_time);
END
```

[DATA DIAGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y781J.png)

Comment: Edit your question. Select the text. Press the code button { } above the text box. Next, you need to do a bit more explaining than "it's not working" - we aren't mind readers (though I can see some obvious problems with your code)

Comment: Thanks for the editing... you are right! When i run it i take an error like this #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Comment: "Not working" means nothing. Please explain exactly. In fact read & act on [mcve]. That includes DDL & only using diagrams/links if you also put any of their text/tables inline as text.

Comment: I allready put the database diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should run the update of the charge on that way; if you're wanting to set the values of a row in a trigger that is firing because the row has been updated, all you need to do is

```
SET new.columnname = somevalue
```

To set the value of columnname on the updated row. You don't kick off another update of the table within the update trigger that is firing upon update of the table.

Next, you seem to be joining all the rows in movies together with all the rows in renting, which will surely return hundreds or thousands of rows, and you're trying to set one value. This is broken logic: which of the thousands of movie rows do you want MySQL to pick? It won't choose; the logic is broken

Step back for moment and consider: this is an update trigger of the renting table. It fires for every row updated and the row being updated is accessible by the `new.` specifier. There is a new.movie_id property - that's the id of the movie being updated right now. If you want some data out of the movies table, select it based on the movie id in the new row (the row being updated) I.e. new.movie_id

You don't need the temp view either - if you want to know the return date, surely that is also part of the `new.` row

All in, this trigger should probably be a single line along the following idea:

```
SET new.charge = (select rate from movies where id = new.movie_id) * datediff(date_rented, date_returned, day)
```

As a side comment, I think the front end app should be doing this, not triggers in the database